# Azure VM 'goes offline' from time to time and resolves itself, not sure why?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

So I have a server running in Northern Europe, it works fine for the most past, but, once or twice a month it goes offline for half an hour so, and I have to wait for it to come back again.
SSH not possible during this time.
Azure Portal says VM is up and running - I can restart it and it restarts.. 
I don't have access to Bastion so I can't actually log in via WWW, however I can safely say that the VM state does not change during this time. It is almost like a virtual LAN cable is being pulled out and then somebody comes and puts it back in..
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the diagnostics page whilst it is not accesible, you can view a screen shot of the servers screen. You could also try connecting using the serial console

Comment: Thanks! Serial console is what I've been wanting for ages, I just didn't know what it was called. Which diagnostics page are you referring to? I looked around but not certain which page you're referring to.

Comment: If you go to the boot diagnostics tab on the VM you should be able to see a screen shot

Comment: Great, thanks! Sorry for late reply.

Comment: It happened again - I was able to access the site using the Serial Console - all up and running as expected, load average fine, all checks out. Boot diagnostics tab just printed what the Serial Console had.. The WWW is also accessible outbound.. the server just isn't accessible inbound.